# ReactJS with StrictMode swallows some log messages

Tags: reactjs, logging, react-redux, react-hooks

I got a weird observation when upgrading reacts versions: When upgrading react from 16.8.6 to 17.0.1, the new application swallows some of the log messages even though the result rendered on the web page is still exactly the same. Could anybody help me to explain it?

In more detail:

This is my component:

```
let componentCount = 0;
let returnCount = 0;
let useSelectorCount = 0;
let useEffectCount = 0;

const Comp04ClickButtonPage = (): JSX.Element => {
    componentCount++;
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - START ----------------------`);

    // useSelector
    const stringValueState = useSelector((rootState: RootState): string => {
        useSelectorCount++;
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] selectorCount: ${useSelectorCount}`);
        const result = rootState.comp04ClickButtonSlice.stringValue;
        return result;
    });
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - after useSelectorCount`);

    // useEffect
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        useEffectCount++;
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] effectCount: ${useEffectCount}.`);
        dispatch(thunkComp04ClickButton(`${new Date().getTime()}`));
    }, [dispatch]);
    console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - after useEffect`);

    const onClickButton = () => {
        componentCount = returnCount = useSelectorCount = useEffectCount = 0; // reset counts
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] onClickNewValue`);
        dispatch(thunkComp04ClickButton(`Random ${new Date().getTime()}`));
    };

    // render
    returnCount++;
    return (
        <div>
            {console.log(`[${componentCount}] renderCount: ${returnCount}`)}
            <div>
                [{componentCount}], useEffect: {useEffectCount}, useSelectorCount: {useSelectorCount}, returnCount: {returnCount}
            </div>
            <button onClick={onClickButton}>Click Button</button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Comp04ClickButtonPage;
```

Excerpt from the `package.json` of the old version:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
  "react": "^16.8.6",
  "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
  "react-intl": "^5.10.2",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
  "react-use": "^15.3.4",
  "redux": "^4.0.5",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
}
```

Excerpt from the `package.json` of the new version:

```
"dependencies": {
  "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.0",
  "react": "^17.0.1",
  "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
  "react-intl": "^5.10.16",
  "react-redux": "^7.2.2",
  "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
  "react-scripts": "^4.0.1",
  "react-use": "^15.3.8",
  "redux": "^4.0.5",
  "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.8",
  "typescript": "^4.1.3",
  "web-vitals": "^1.1.0"
}
```

The log of the old version:
[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLr3V.png)

The log of the new version:
[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2KH0.png)

To be more specific in that new version's screenshot:

**Missing 1:**
The componentCount is changed from `[1]` to `[2]`, the actual log messages are:

```
[1] renderCount: 1
[2] selectorCount: 2
```

But if we look at the code:

```
    const Comp04ClickButtonPage = (): JSX.Element => {
        componentCount++;
        console.log(`[${componentCount}] component - START ----------------------`);
```

Hence, *the expected log messages are*:

```
[1] renderCount: 1
[2] component - START ----------------------
[2] selectorCount: 2
```

I don't understand how `componentCount` is increased but that `component - START` log message is missing???

**Missing 2:**
In the log messages of the new version ([Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2KH0.png)), the whole logs when the component is executed the 4th time is missing (while they appeared in the old version - [Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLr3V.png)):

```
[4] component - START ----------------------
[4] selectorCount: 7
[4] component - after useSelectorCount
[4] component - after useEffect
[4] renderCount: 4
```

*The expectation* is that those log messages should appear when running with the new React version the same way they appeared in the old version.

Note: the result in the webpage is still `[4], useEffect: 1, useSelectorCount: 7, returnCount: 4`. It means the line `componentCount++` is executed while the log message of the very next line `console.log([${componentCount}] component - START ----------------------);` is not printed. How is that possible?

P/S: The full code: https://github.com/khoitnm/practice-react-redux 
In that repository, there are 2 projects `pro-00-old-react-version` and `pro-01-redux-simple`. The only difference is `package.json` file. All of the other files are exactly the same.

Comment: 1. This may be because you use [strictmode](https://github.com/khoitnm/practice-react-redux/blob/main/pro-01-redux-simple/src/index.tsx#L14). I don't understand what you mean with 2, what did you expect? You could see console.logs with different numbers because an effect and a selector can be run without causing a re render so what you see in console does not have to be the same as what is rendered.

Comment: I am also pretty sure [this](https://github.com/khoitnm/practice-react-redux/blob/main/pro-01-redux-simple/src/index.tsx#L11) is no longer needed, just import App and see if that makes it more predictable.

Comment: @HMR the point of "Missing 2" is: the `componentCount` is increased from 3 to 4 (as we saw in the final result on the web page). However, all of the whole log messages with that componentCount = 4 are missing (for example `[4] component - START ----------------------`, etc.)

The expectation is those log messages should appear the same way when we run on the old version [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLr3V.png)

Comment: @HMR I updated the question to included the "expected log message" and "expectation" sections.

Comment: @HMR I also tried to replace `const App = require('./App').default;` by `import App from './App'` and putting that import to the top of the file as you suggested, but the result is still the same (I still keep the code on Github the same though so that your comment is still pointing to the same code).

Comment: So 1 and 2 are the same, already told you that removing strictmode would solve 1 so that would solve 2 as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, @HMR! I use replaced `<React.StrictMode>` by `React.Fragment` and then the log messages in both old and new versions are the same now. However, one very interesting thing is: both versions now trigger the functional component only 2 times. The final result on the web page is: `[2], useEffect: 1, useSelectorCount: 5, returnCount: 2`, and the log also show corresponding messages.

Comment: Then the next questions are: (1) Why `<React.StrictMode>` makes the component triggered 4 times instead of 2?
(2) And why `<React.StrictMode>` cause missing log messages?
(3) And as suggested by many articles, the StrictMode is useful for us and we should use it to avoid many mistakes, is there any way to use it without causing those problems?

You helped me a lot, @MHR; and if possible, some more explanation to help me understand why it runs like that behind the scene would make my day! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictmode when run during developing will run hooks/renders multiple times to detect memory leaks that is why your component renders 4 times in strict mode instead of 2.

I did clone your repo and found something interesting. Without changing anything the log

```
console.log(`[${componentCount}] selectorCount: ${useSelectorCount}`);
```

Jumps from 1 to 3, value 2 is never logged. This may be an interesting case for Chrome or React devs. You do have a point that console logs are not shown but the console log is definitely executed since `useSelectorCount++` is in the same block of code as the log. All this goes away when strict mode isn't used.

As for not removing strict mode; if you look on stack overflow for it you'll find strict mode is the perfect foot gun, I'm sure the devs are proud of it and won't recommend removing it but if you're trying to learn React and predict when components are rendered and hooks are executed then having it on will confuse you.

Comment: Thank you @HMR, your explanation helps me to understand a lot more.